# Replace dictionary values with a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

A dictionary like this:

```
{' ': None, 'a': None, 'b': None, 'c': None, 'd': None, 'e': None, 'f': None, 'g': None, 'h': None, 'i': None, 'j': None, 'k': None, 'l': None, 'm': None, 'n': None, 'o': None, 'p': None, 'q': None, 'r': None, 's': None, 't': None, 'u': None, 'v': None, 'w': None, 'x': None, 'y': None, 'z': None}
```

And a

```
list = [0,1,2,....26]
```

And I want to replace all values `None` with values from a list.
So that we can have a dict

```
{'': 0, 'a' :1....'z': 26}
```

Comment: There are too many ways to approach this problem. The answers would just turn into a straw-poll for which one people liked. The best thing is to do some research on the topic yourself, find two or three, _analyze_ them, determine if they work for you or not, and _try them out_. Come to us when you have a specific question about something you have attempted to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a loop or dictionary-comprehension like this:

```
d = {' ': None, 'a': None, 'b': None, 'c': None, 'd': None, 'e': None, 'f': None, 'g': None, 'h': None, 'i': None, 'j': None, 'k': None, 'l': None, 'm': None, 'n': None, 'o': None, 'p': None, 'q': None, 'r': None, 's': None, 't': None, 'u': None, 'v': None, 'w': None, 'x': None, 'y': None, 'z': None}  
l = [x for x in range(len(d.keys()))]
d2 = { k:l[i] for i, k in enumerate(d.keys()) }
print(d2)
# Outputs:
# {' ': 0, 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5, 'f': 6, 'g': 7, 'h': 8, 'i': 9, 'j': 10, 'k': 11, 'l': 12, 'm': 13, 'n': 14, 'o': 15, 'p': 16, 'q': 17, 'r': 18, 's': 19, 't': 20, 'u': 21, 'v': 22, 'w': 23, 'x': 24, 'y': 25, 'z': 26}
```

Comment: `enumerate(d)` is sufficient; a `dict` iterator already returns the keys. However, keep in mind that there is no guarantee that the iterator return the keys in the order requested by the question (unless you are using Python 3.7 or later, and you know that the keys were *inserted* in that order). It would be best to explicitly sort the keys first.